# Input type submit not redirecting to form action

Tags: html

I created a form that can send an email, but it is not redirecting to the php script when hitting submit.

Here is the form by the way

Code:

```
<form method="post" id="myForm" name="myForm" action="mail_handler.php">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="single-form">
        <label>* FULL NAME</label> <input class="form-control" type="text" name="full_name" id="full_name" placeholder="Enter full name" required="">
      </div>
    </div><!-- Nice Select -->
    <!-- First Name -->
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="single-form">
        <label>* Email Address</label> <input class="form-control" type="email" name="emailAdd" id="emailAdd" placeholder="Enter email" required="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="single-form">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn apply-btn mt-30">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

and here is the mail_handler.php.

```php
<?php
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
    
    require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
    require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
    require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';
    
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
         if(!empty($_POST['full_name']) && !empty($_POST['emailAdd'])){
                $mail = new PHPMailer;
                $mail->IsSMTP();
                $mail->IsHTML(true);
                $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // enable SMTP authentication
                $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl"; // sets the prefix to the servier
    
                $mail->Host = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com"; // sets yahoo as the SMTP server
                $mail->Port = 465; // set the SMTP port
                $mail->Username = "my username"; // yahoo username
                $mail->Password = "my pass"; // yahoo password
    
                $full_name = $_POST['full_name'];
                $emailAdd = $_POST['emailAdd'];
    
                $subject = "Webpage Client Feedback";
    
                $to = "cremlicofficial@yahoo.com";
                $subject = "WEBPAGE: PRE-APPLICATION";
    
                $mail->From = "cremlicit@yahoo.com";
                $mail->FromName = "CREMLIC ADMIN";
                $mail->AddAddress("cremlic@yahoo.com");
                $mail->AddCC('cegabrillo@yahoo.com.ph');
                $mail->AddCC('ksgaro@yahoo.com');
                $mail->Subject = "WEBPAGE:PRE-APPLICATION";
                $mail->Body = "To Whom it may concern, \r\n"
                             . "A visitor submits a pre-application information, please see details below. \r\n \r\n"
                             . "Name: " . $full_name . " \r\n"
                             . "Email: " . $emailAdd;
                $mail->AddEmbeddedImage('./images/1593998909.jpg', 'palogo', '1593998909.jpg');
                if(!$mail->Send()) {
                    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Message was not sent. \r\nMailer error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo.'");window.history.go(-1);</script>';
                }
          }else{
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Error Occured! \r\nPlease fill up fields: Name, Address and Contact No.");window.history.go(-1);</script>';
          }
        }
    ?>
```

I am 100% sure that both HTML file and PHP script is on the same folder. Is there any problem with these line of codes?

Answer (score -1):

The form is working fine, kindly check the location of mail_handler.php if its in the same folder or in different folder. Also share mail_handler.php code so we can check if there's any issue with the code.

Comment: yes mail_handler.php is in the same folder. I've added the script

Comment: Are you using generated app password from yahoo or your yahoo login password?

Comment: I do have a generated app password from yahoo

Comment: After submitting the form are you getting any error?

Comment: No I'm not getting any error. It is literally stuck on the same page

Comment: Well then if the form is hosted online then try to clear cache and check, maybe because of cache its not working, I tried the code on local environment and the code is working fine.